# Mac Keychain permissions across multiple apps

Tags: macos, cocoa, keychain

I have 2 applications with different bundle identifiers.

1 app is sandboxed and the other app is not.

The non-sandboxed app writes an entry to the Keychain.

How do I allow the sandboxed app to read and modify the Keychain entry without prompting the user to allow access to it?

The sandboxed app is installed at a later stage so I cannot use `SecTrustedApplicationCreateFromPath` because the path does not yet exist.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to initially create your own ACL which allows access to all applications.

Then you can overwrite the ACL again once you're back in your sandboxed app to restrict access once more, to only trusted applications (yours and any XPC processes you may have).

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7838791/creating-keychain-item-with-type-web-form-password-on-mac-os-x) for details on how to construct this permissive ACL.